# Disable format-on-save in VSCode for Golang

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have a comment on the first line of the Go file. The purpose of this comment is to act as a script that the OS loader can use to execute the file. E.g.

```go
//usr/bin/env echo hello
```

For comments that are on the first line of the Go file, how do I disable auto-format-on-save? Disabling `formatOnSave` does not seem to help.

Answer (score -1):

For comments that are on the first line of the Go file, where you don't want auto-format to change anything, one has to disable `formatOnSave` and `organizeImports`, both.

```json
    "[go]": {
        /*
         *
         * editor.formatOnSave and source.organizeImports, both, need to be
         * disabled in order to not add a space after // on line 1 in
         * https://gist.github.com/gurjeet/3121b2e373e61873c5a6e96d72b6c1c6
         */
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": false
        }
    }
```